# Set default values from application.properties to an @Entity

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa

How do you put defaults values from application.properties to an Entity?

This works but is not what I need.

```java
@Entity
@Data
public class SomeEntity {
    
    private String value = "default";
}
```

I know that this code doesn't work because I've used `new()`, so Spring doesn't inject the value. Adding `@Component` didn't change.

```java
@Entity
@Data
public class SomeEntity {
    
    @Value("${value}")
    private String value;
}

//other place
SomeEntity se = new SomeEntity()
System.out.println(se.value); //null
```

how can i add `${value}` to something like this?
(I like this way because database knows the default value too)

```java
@Entity
@Data
public class SomeEntity {
    
    @Column(columnDefinition = "varchar(255) default [INJECT_HERE]");
    private String value;
}
```

Comment: An Entity is not a Bean. Spring cannot inject properties in it because it does not create them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot inject properties in an Entity via Spring because you create it yourself. If you really want to have a default value driven by a property, I would do a factory with the injected value that creates those `SomeEntity` and set the given property with the right field.